# Ayuda en Taller de Estudio

Tags: java, array

Tengo un problema con mi codigo tengo que realizar este trabajo, y no puedo calcular los valores totales leyendo un archivo externo, con estas caracteriticas en Java.

[image: Ejercicio a realizar]

Llevo este codigo trabajado, que me calcula los valores del puntaje de los competidores pero todos en array unidimensional, pero el el calculo total de cada uno, ahí estoy medio mareado.

ucn es la librería de la Universidad que modifica algunas sentencias de java.

Saludos

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import ucn.*;
public class TallerTP {


   String Paises[] = new String[8];
   String Pilotos[] = new String[8];
   double Horas[] = new double[8];
   int Puntaje[] = new int[8];
   String PilotosPuntaje[][] = new String[8][2];



  public static void main(String[] args) { 
    TallerTP pv = new TallerTP();
    pv.cargar();
    //StdOut.println("Ordenados Paises");
    //pv.ordenarPaises();
    //pv.imprimir();
    StdOut.println("Ordenados Horas");
    pv.ordenarHoras();
    pv.puntaje();
    pv.imprimir();
  }

  public void cargar(){
  In entrada=new In ("wrc.txt");

    while(!entrada.isEmpty()){
      for(int i=0; i<8; i++){
        Paises[i] = entrada.readString();
        Pilotos[i] = entrada.readString();
        Horas[i] = entrada.readDouble();
       } 
    }
   entrada.close(); 
  }

//  public void ordenarPaises(){
//    for(int k=0; k<Paises.length; k++){
//      for(int f=0; f<Paises.length-1-k; f++){
//        if (Paises[f].compareTo(Paises[f+1])>0){
//          String auxpais;
//          auxpais = Paises[f];
//          Paises[f] = Paises[f+1];
//          Paises[f+1] = auxpais;
//          String auxpiloto;
//          auxpiloto = Pilotos[f];
//          Pilotos[f] = Pilotos[f+1];
//          Pilotos[f+1] = auxpiloto;
//          double auxhoras;
//          auxhoras = Horas[f];
//          Horas[f] = Horas[f+1];
//          Horas[f+1] = auxhoras;
//        }
//      }
//    }
//
//  }

   public void ordenarHoras(){
    for(int k=0; k<Horas.length; k++){
      for(int f=0; f<Horas.length-1-k; f++){
        if (Horas[f]>Horas[f+1]){
          double auxhoras;
          auxhoras = Horas[f];
          Horas[f] = Horas[f+1];
          Horas[f+1] = auxhoras;
          String auxpais;
          auxpais = Paises[f];
          Paises[f] = Paises[f+1];
          Paises[f+1] = auxpais;
          String auxpiloto;
          auxpiloto = Pilotos[f];
          Pilotos[f] = Pilotos[f+1];
          Pilotos[f+1] = auxpiloto;
        }
      }
    }

  }

   public void puntaje(){
     String p = Paises[0];
     String t = Pilotos[0];
     int x = 0;
     int a = 0;
     int c = 0;
     int Puntos[] = {25,18,15,12,10,8,6,4,2,1};
      for (int k=0; k<Puntaje.length; k++) {
        if (c < 10 && p.equals(Paises[k])) {
          p = Paises[k];
          Puntaje[k] = Puntos[c];
          c = c + 1;
        }else{
          c = 0;
          Puntaje[k] = Puntos[c];
          p = Paises[k]; 
          c = c + 1;
        }
      }
   }

  public void imprimir() {
    for(int f=0; f<Paises.length; f++){
     StdOut.println(Paises[f] + " - "+ Pilotos[f] +" - "+ Horas[f] +" - "+Puntaje[f]);
    }
     //for(int d=0; d<PilotosPuntaje.length; d++){
     //StdOut.println(PilotosPuntaje[d][0] +" - "+ PilotosPuntaje[d][1]);
    // }
  }


}
```

Comment: puedes mostrar como vienen los datos en el archivo de texto plano

Comment: Este es link donde se encuentra el archivo como tal, https://pastebin.com/JHrT4pp9

Comment: ah no, solo se manejar archivos csv

Answer (score 0):

En el método `puntaje()` tenés las variables `t`, `x` y `a` que no se usan nunca.

Además la condición `p.equals(paises[k])` sólo se cumple cuando hay dos paises iguales seguidos porque le estás volviendo a asignar a `p` el mismo valor que tiene, y si no se cumple le pasa a `puntaje[k]` el primer valor de `puntos[]` porque `c` vale cero.

Igual `puntaje[]` no haría falta ordenarlo porque los valores son fijos. Si lo que querés es que te devuelva los tres primeros puestos de algún país, podrías guardar el nombre del país en una variable afuera del ciclo y después de ordenarlos recorrer el arreglo hasta que el `país[k]` coincida tres veces con esa variable.